# How would you go about creating a floating bridge across a large body of water?

Tags: transportation, infrastructure

So here's the idea: For large bodies of water, it becomes progressively harder and more expensive to build traditional bridges as the distance and depth increases. Would it be possible to create a sturdy bridge that floated on the water without needing any auxiliary support?

For example: Kyushu(island), Japan to Busan, South Korea (Yes, I know they have typhoons). It's a major trade route and would benefit from 100mph trains instead of 30mph boats.

Comment: Here are some big challenges I see with this project: If its floating, can the length sway in the currents? How will you allow ships to pass? It will need the deck 100ft above sea level in parts.

Comment: Hello Danny, welcome to [worldbuilding.se]. Per the [help/on-topic], our goal is to help you build an imaginary world. As written, you appear to be asking an engineering question about the Real World. We host Real World questions, but only in the context of worldbuilding, which means you need to explain *what's different* about your imaginary world such that the question couldn't be asked more effectively on one of the Real World Stacks. Should you be asking this question here? If so, please explain why.

Comment: In the mean time, I can tell you why no one would choose to do this. Even metal stretches, and over any distance of more than a mile or two, the floating part of the bridge will move back-and-forth and up-and-down, eventually tearing the moorings away from the land-based mounts. As wind and wave disturbance increases, this becomes worse. Long before this happens, your trains would be forced to abandon the route. It's a clever worldbuilding idea in that you can use Clarkean Magic to believably dampen the oscillations - but in the Real World we're not there yet.

Comment: Jbh there's plenty of examples of actual floating bridges. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_pontoon_bridges

Comment: Great point @SurpriseDog. It seems like they are generally limited to <2km and lakes/rivers/canals.

Comment: Not on the ocean, oceans have currents and heave.

Comment: I'm torn on this one. It's clearly in the field of science fiction, since the science to accomplish this is just outside of what we're capable of. I think it would be physically possible, but not economically viable, and it would make an interesting discussion. I'm voting to re-open.

Answer (score 5):

Frame challenge: a more "usual" bridge would be hard enough, and annoying enough to build.

A pontoon or floating type bridge would block crossing ocean traffic over the full distance, getting people on both sides annoyed at you. Normal bridge spans would permit ocean vessels to pass under the bridge. Tunnels would allow ships to pass over. And it seems the longer span in the crossing you suggest is about twenty times as long as the longest pontoon bridge currently in existence.

The [Hong Kong-Macau bridge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hong_Kong%E2%80%93Zhuhai%E2%80%93Macau_Bridge) is a 55 km combination bridge and tunnel link between Hong Kong and Macau. It is possible to drive private cars, though this is reported to be expensive and require extensive paperwork. This link is about half the distance suggested in the question. (I could not get Google Maps to report the distance, but that is mostly my inability. I just eye-balled it. If somebody wants to give a better figure I would welcome the edit.) And there are some islands in the middle that could potentially be used as supports.

Depending on the depth of the ocean in this area, it might be possible to put additional supports or artificial islands such that bridges could be constructed.

It is by no means an easy question to decide if such a bridge would be within current technology. It would require a great deal of engineering evaluation of the ocean bottom, the depth of the ocean, the nature of earthquake activity nearby, and a bunch of other things that I'm not remembering just now.

The financial viability would also be a huge question. There are folks who claim that the HK-M link is far from financially viable. They claim that the current traffic does not come close to paying for the upkeep. Such structures require substantial inspection and maintenance programs.

The HK-M link has been open for a few years now, and has stood up to several typhoons. It is thus possible to build bridges of the general length suggested that will withstand the weather.

Comment: There is an [165 km long viaduct in China](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Danyang–Kunshan_Grand_Bridge) and an [157 km long viaduct in Taiwan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Changhua%E2%80%93Kaohsiung_Viaduct). There is a [57 km long tunnel betwee Switzerland and Italy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gotthard_Base_Tunnel).

Comment: @AlexP The two viaducts are over land. Putting a bridge over land is of a different character to a bridge over ocean.  The tunnel is also a different character. These are all spectacular engineering works, but don't tell us if a bridge over this particular ocean span is achievable just now.